# Get order id after Place order in checkout onepage in magento?

Tags: magento, checkout

I need to get order id after submitting an order (before redirecting from checkout/onepage) in Magento. My model method is working fine with no errors.

I have added:

```
$Order_Id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
```

Before the redirecting statement:

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

But the value of `$Order_id` is `NULL`. How do I retrieve the new order ID?

Comment: are u talk about "before redirecting from checkout/onepage/success"

Comment: also,where are you want to retrieve $orderid

Comment: Yes..you are right...I want to retrieve $order_id In Controller method (saveOrderAction()) or in my custom model method..

Comment: @Mostaqmahmud you get order id only after saveOrder method

Comment: @Keyu Shah....i got it...tnx......